# Migrate to webpack 2, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'exports'

Tags: webpack

I am trying to migrate my current project (on Angular2) to webpack2.
This my config for webpack:

https://gist.github.com/kunashir/5174a237d7404079ebd8f343deee0037

But I have got an error:

```
ERROR in ./app/common/forms/ckeditor.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'exports' in 
'/home/al1/projects/voltmobi/ytaxiweb/ui/app/common/forms'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
             You need to specify 'exports-loader' instead of 'exports',
             see https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed
```

However I don't use exports-loader and it not in config for webpack1.

String from module which bring the error:

```
 import { Constants } from 'config/constants'
```

Module for import looks like:

```
export class Constants {
  static API = {
    PATH: '/web_api'
  }
}
```

I'm newbie with Webpack.

Maybe I was wrong and problem in:

```
let loadCKEDITOR = require('bundle-loader?lazy!exports?window.CKEDITOR!ckeditor/ckeditor')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `exports-loader` in your config, but you specify it [inline](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline):

```
let loadCKEDITOR = require('bundle-loader?lazy!exports?window.CKEDITOR!ckeditor/ckeditor')
                                               ^^^^^^^
```

As the error suggests, this should be `exports-loader`.

```
let loadCKEDITOR = require('bundle-loader?lazy!exports-loader?window.CKEDITOR!ckeditor/ckeditor')
```